# How can to Remote Access ASP.NET 6 Core Web API from another VM

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to build a Web API using ASP.NET Core 6. just a simple CRUD example.
I can access and interact with the API through the link

https://localhost:7270/swagger/index.html

Now I want to access it from another VM.
pls show me how can do that? tks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using windows server, you could host the application inside the IIS.

Short step:
1.You should install the host bundle for the asp.net core
2.Create the IIS web application and add some binding information
3.You should publish the application into the IIS website or folder
4.Start the application and on other VM you could use IP address: Port to access the IIS .net core application.

For how host .net core 6 application inside IIS, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows/windows server and kestrel:

1 - Change application URL from `https://localhost:7270` to `https://0.0.0.0:7270`.

2 - Go to `Control Panel / Network and Sharing Center / Advanced sharing settings` and switch to `Turn On` in all sections.

3 - Go to `Control Panel / System` check button allow remote.

and go to second VM and call first vm with ip and application port